# iterate multidimensional array and retrieve both single value together with array values

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following array that I need to iterate. I need to get the header value and then each "team" and "picture" value. How can I do that? I tried this but that give me an error "Illegal string offset 'team'".

[image]

```
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($fileName);
    
    //print_r($xml);
    $eventHeader = $xml->title;
    
    // standings array
        $standings_arr=array();
        $standings_arr["standings"]=array("header" =>(string)$eventHeader);
 
    foreach($xml->row as $item)
    {
         $standings_item=array(
        "team" => (string)$item->team,
        "picture" => (string)$item->picture,
        "v" => (string)$item->v,
        "f" => (string)$item->f,
        "p" => (string)$item->p
       );
        array_push($standings_arr["standings"], $standings_item);
    }

    foreach ($standings_arr as $row ) {
      
      $header = $row['header'];

      if (is_array($row)) 
      { 
        foreach ( $row as $key => $value ) {
          echo $value['team'];
        }
      }
    }
```

Can someone guide me please?

Comment: Just check it before the second loop `if (is_array($row)) { foreach ($row...) { ... } }` because `header` element is not an array

Answer (score 0):

If header is first item in array you could `shift` the array and then iterate:

```php
$header = array_shift($standings);

foreach ($standings as $standing) {
    if (! is_array($standing)) continue;
    
    if (isset($standing['team'])) {
        echo $standing['team'];
    }
}
```

Comment: And what if there is a "footer" key, in this array, for example ?

Comment: I have now changed the code above, I now get the header value but stil get the same warning on "echo $value['team'];"

Comment: I edit the code above, if keep not working edit your question with the entire array definition.

Comment: Its not working so I edit the code below.

Comment: I got it working like this         foreach ($standings_arr as $standing)
        {
          //echo "<br><b># $num</b><br>";
          foreach ($standing as $key=>$value)
          {
            if (! is_array($value))
            {
              //echo "$key: $value <br>";
              echo $value ."<br>";
            }
            else
            {
              if (isset($value['team'])) {
                echo $value['team'] ."<br>";
              }
            }
          }
        }